# Eradicate All Traces Of MS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I likely have remnants of old Visual Studio installations, but I want to start fresh. Regardless of how many times I uninstall, when I try to install the latest community edition of VS I never get to choose what drive to install it on. It just automatically uses my C: drive. My C: drive is a small SSD reserved for the OS and cannot store the program. How do I get a clean start?